# Stopping divs from moving after they reach 2 per row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to stop `div`s from changing their position after they reach 2 `div`s per row and window is too small to show both of them. I would like them to stay at the same position but having problem with doing it myself.

Here is code I got:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  background-color: darkgrey;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: auto;
}

div>div {
  margin: 0.5rem;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

div:nth-child( 4n) {
  clear: left;
}

img {
  width: 320px;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.border {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: white;
}

.txt {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  left: -8;
  width: 320px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -7px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  max-width: 100%;
  color: white;
}

@media( max-width: 1024px) {
  div:nth-child( 2n + 3) {
    clear: left;
  }
  div:nth-child( 4n) {
    clear: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="border">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png">
    <div class="txt">div text 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png">
    <div class="txt">div text 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png">
    <div class="txt">Omelette du fromage</div>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png">
    <div class="txt">How you doin?</div>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png">
    <div class="txt">div text 5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png">
    <div class="txt">div text 6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Labels should be on point with their layout but they are not previewing as they should.
Here is link to other CSS editor which does it better: http://www.cssdesk.com/7kW7k

Comment: It is "omelette au fromage", not "omelette du fromage" :)

Comment: It is from cartoon series called Dexter's Laboratory :P.

Comment: did you try to remove ``margin: 0.5rem;`` at ``div > div`` in css

Comment: I need this margin.

Comment: Do you only want only two images in a row or to align the label right?

Comment: @AESTHETICS When you show 2 images and document shrink picture should shrink or cause overflow?

Comment: When browser window reaches width below 1024 it should show 2 divs per row instead of 3.

Comment: @Patrick Mlr alignment would be nice but i think it is more of this snippet tool error.

Comment: @AESTHETICS OK, suppose browser width is 500px what should we do next? scrollbar or shrinking images?

Comment: Shrink would be great.

Comment: If it would be possible to resize and make it responsive as well but it would fold when width reaches below 1024 to 2 divs per row and after that shrinks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewritten you layout using flexbox and perfored some style optimizations.

Assuming you want adding scrollbars when 2 images in the row and page is shrinking. Result:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  
  /* for centering block both horizontally and vertically */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* maximum 3 items, (320px + 2px border + 0.5rem margin-left + 0.5rem margin-right) × 3 */
  max-width: calc(322px * 3 + 0.5rem * 6);
  /* minimum 2 items, (320px + 2px border + 0.5rem margin-left + 0.5rem margin-right) × 2 */
  min-width: calc(322px * 2 + 0.5rem * 4);
}

.wrapper > div {
  margin: 0.5rem;
}

img {
  width: 320px;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.txt {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="border">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png">
    <div class="txt">div text 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png">
    <div class="txt">div text 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png">
    <div class="txt">Omelette du fromage</div>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png">
    <div class="txt">How you doin?</div>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png">
    <div class="txt">div text 5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png">
    <div class="txt">div text 6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can test resizing in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d7sLgj1t/).

If you want image shrinking you can add media query for this:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  
  /* for centering block both horizontally and vertically */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* maximum 3 items, (320px + 2px border + 0.5rem margin-left + 0.5rem margin-right) × 3 */
  max-width: calc(322px * 3 + 0.5rem * 6);
}

.wrapper > div {
  margin: 0.5rem;
}

img {
  width: 320px;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.border {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  position: relative;
}

.txt {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 10px 20px;
  color: white;
}

@media (max-width: 750px) {
  .border {
    width: calc(50% - 2rem);
  }
  
  .border > img {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="border">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png">
    <div class="txt">div text 1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png">
    <div class="txt">div text 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png">
    <div class="txt">Omelette du fromage</div>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png">
    <div class="txt">How you doin?</div>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png">
    <div class="txt">div text 5</div>
  </div>
  <div class="border">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png">
    <div class="txt">div text 6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Test resizing in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xxs18Lt0/).

Comment: I understood how this line of code works  max-width: calc(322px * 3 + 0.5rem * 6); and i changed size of image to 323.33px so it works exactly how i wanted: https://jsfiddle.net/0nocysm9/ Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I added a left property and thus managed to get the alignment better:

```
.txt {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  width: 320px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -6px;
  left: -7px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 4px;
  max-width: 100%;
  color: white;
}
```

Fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mjpLmqwx/

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html,
body {
 background-color: darkgrey;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
html {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
body {
}
.wrapper {
  margin: auto;
  width:100%;

}
.txt {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    left: -8;
    width: 320px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    max-width: 100%;
    color: white;
    margin: 0px;
}
div > div {
    margin: 0.5rem;
}




img {
width:100%;
}
.border {
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: white;
    width: 47%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="border">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png">
    <div class="txt">div text 1</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="border">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png">
    <div class="txt">div text 2</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="border">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png">
    <div class="txt">Omelette du fromage</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="border">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png">
    <div class="txt">How you doin?</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="border">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png">
    <div class="txt">div text 5</div>
  </div> 
  <div class="border">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/VCsr2MH.png">
    <div class="txt">div text 6</div>
  </div> 
</div>
```